# Deploying nodejs/mongoose to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, buildpack, mlab

This is my first try at Heroku. I was able to "deploy successful" on heroku, but when visiting my app, it says "**application failed**."

I followed this guide:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-mongodb-with-a-node-application-on-heroku

I think the tricky thing is because I'm using Mongoose, it may not relate well with the URI. I'm also using mlab addon.

Here's my setup for my backend:

```
        var request = require('request');
    var app = express();
    var mongoCredentialss = require('/mongo_credentialss.json');
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    var path = require('path');

    // connect to the database
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongoCredentials.username + ':' + mongoCredentialss.password + '@ds012345.mlab.com:12345/mydatabase-db');
    mongoose.Promise = Promise;
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on 3000...');
  });
```

I didn't really understand the .env, to make it work locally, I just stored my username and password in a hidden .json file thanks to .gitignore. From the guide though, I just tried embedding URI straight into my node file as a variable to see if that even works. I'm not too sure how 'hidden environments' work...

Later on when I started over, I also kept having a recurring problem with heroku not detecting its standard buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs

****EDIT:

Still seeing some issues. I took out my 'mongo creds' so my server.js file now looks like this:

```
    var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var randtoken = require('rand-token');
var cors = require('cors');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

var conn = mongoose.connection;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

  app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + 3000);
  });
```

Some further context: I have one main project folder, which houses 2 sub folders: backend and frontend. When I deploy it to heroku, I change directory into the main folder to deploy everything.

Also, if it helps, here's what my **package.json** looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.3",
    "my-bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "rand-token": "^0.2.1",
    "request": "^2.74.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "==6.0.0"
  }
}
```

******EDIT 2:
heroku logs can't find my 'backend.js'. Right now, I've got one main project folder directory, inside it is 2 folders: --->backend.js (node)  and --->frontend.js (angular)

My package.json looks like this:

```
**"main": "frontend.js",**
  "scripts": {
    **"start": "node backend.js",**
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I may be misunderstanding how heroku is finding my main .js files. From my understanding 'start' is for the node file, and the 'main' file is for the frontend stuff like angular/html stuff.

Comment: After moving everything out of sub folders into the main folder (backend.js, frontend.js, css files, html files), I can confirm again that I can run my app locally. But when deploying FRESH to a new heroku app, I now get the following logs: 2016-08-27T20:45:26.674272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-27T20:45:28.574699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node backend.js`
2016-08-27T20:45:30.818329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Comment: 2016-08-27T20:45:30.753675+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753686+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753687+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753687+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753692+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/backend.js'
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753694+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753693+00:00 app[web.1]:     at

Comment: Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753695+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753696+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-08-27T20:45:30.753697+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to connect Mongoose to your MLab database by doing this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
```

When you are using an addon on Heroku, the provider (MLab in this case) will create a database for you, and then store the connection details (the URL with the database host, username, password, port, etc.) as an environment variable that your application can use.

That's why you need to pass that environment variable `process.env.MONGODB_URI` into `mongoose.connect`: it will connect you to the right database =)

**UPDATE**: Since you updated your question, I noticed another issue that will prevent this from running. You need to tell your app to listen on a specific Heroku port (not `3000`).

What you should do is modify your `app.listen(3000)` call to instead say: `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);` This will force your application run correctly on both Heroku AND you local development box.

Comment: Whoa! Sorry if I misunderstand this, but to clarify, I don't even need the mlab addon in Heroku? I do already have an mlab account, but thought I would need the addon to make it sync.......kinda like how I needed a separate postgresql database to make it work with another app I have. Anyway, from the guide, it seems like the .env is made as a separate file in the terminal........is that true, or is it just something I type all in the server.js file I have?

Comment: You do need the mlab addon. Once you've added it, that special environment variable will exist magically for your app, and you can then connect to that database by using that code I pasted above. In your example code you were connecting to what looks like ANOTHER separate database you have. But you want to do it the way I am showing you to connect to the mlab one instead =)

Comment: Wow, you're fast! I'm pretty excited about testing it now, going to report back soon, thanks buddy! :)

Comment: just did a: heroku logs --tails   found that I may be deploying the wrong part of my folder directory. Gonna give it another try deploying it from the 'backend' folder to make it easier to find my package.json ...which doesn't make sense b/c I'm thinking i need to deploy the whole thing rather than backend stuff.

Comment: I also just saw your update and added in more details into my answer, please see the updated text. You need to change your `app.listen()` call to work on Herkou properly as well =)

Comment: just made a new edit detailing my code after I did a heroku logs --tail; it can't find my 'backend.js'.......i'm thinking it has to do with the way I setup my package.json

Comment: For the heck of it, here's my Procfile in the root directory of my app: web: node backend.js

Comment: What happens when you run `node backend.js` locally in the root of your project folder on your local machine?

Comment: add following like to package.json file"scripts": 
{
    "start": "node backend.js"
  }

Comment: Locally it works fine. For the backend, I use a "node backend.js" for it to run on port 3000. Then, on a separate terminal tab, I run my "frontend.js" via "serve --p 5000".  To Vora, I already have the "start" script in my package.js......just not sure what "main" is referring to.

Comment: ------error from tail:  Error: Cannot find module '/app/backend.js' So, then I tried going into the root of my directory, where my new package.json is stored, and edited the 'start' script to:   "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./backend.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }, ===========> that doesn't do much :(

Comment: This is a separate problem. On Heroku you can only listen on one port, you can't be running on two separate ports like you would normally. You will instead need to create two separate dyno types. You might want to start a separate SO thread about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You require mongo using this line:

```js
 var mongoCredentialss = require('/mongo_credentialss.json');
```

but you've set your password in your mongoCredentials as:

```js
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongoCredentials.username + ':' + mongoCredentialss.password + '@ds012345.mlab.com:12345/mydatabase-db');
```

your username is bound to mongoCredential**s**.username rather than the mongoCredential**ss**.username

Simple typo in the code which is bound to lead to db connection errors.